# Faint, curved white line on monitor. How to get rid of it?

Tags: external-display, visual-artifacts

There is a faint, curved white line on my monitor. The line is not all the way across the monitor, it stops at the middle. It's much more noticeable on bright color images/videos, and less noticeable on greyish or black colors. Tried running my finger nails on the screen but it doesn't seem to be scratch. How do I get rid of the line?

[image: Line]

Comment: `it's much more noticeable on bright color images` ... why the gray picture them?

Comment: what type of monitor is it?

Comment: Try the monitor on another PC. If the line is still there (not perceptible in that photo), then the issue is in the monitor (or, unlikely the cable).